# lldb python equivalent to gdb.GdbError()

Tags: python, gdb, lldb

With gdb python scripting, I can have a helper function throw an error for an unexpected condition:

```
def isFOOEnabled( ):
   sb = gdb.parse_and_eval( "foo" )
   if sb == 0x0:
      raise gdb.GdbError(  "Fatal error." )                              
   return sb
```

I can catch the expression not evaluated error in lldb python like so:

```
def isFOOEnabled( ):
   sb = lldb.frame.EvaluateExpression( "foo" )
   if sb.GetValue() is None:
      return 0
   return sb
```

but I'd also like to force the script to abort like in my gdb version.

For exposition, here is an example of a call to gdb.GdbError:

```
(gdb) info zregisters
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/pjoot/gdb/zinfo.py", line 157, in invoke      
    isFOOEnabled( )
  File "/home/pjoot/gdb/apis/common.py", line 24, in isFOOEnabled      
    sb = gdb.parse_and_eval( "sysblk" )
gdb.error: No symbol "sysblk" in current context.
Error occurred in Python command: No symbol "sysblk" in current context.
(gdb)
```

after which you are back to the (gdb) shell, with a python stacktrace so that you know where things went wrong.  Looks like the string parameter that gdb.GdbError takes is actually lost.

Is there a python lldb.* helper function to do that like gdb.GdbError()?

Comment: There isn't such a thing.  What does it do in gdb scripting?  Does it cause an error to be returned from a command execution that called that helper function?  What about if the script is implementing a breakpoint callback?  I'm not sure what the useful behaviors of this are.

Comment: @JimIngham, I've added an example output for a call to GdbError.  Short answer is that you get a python stacktrace, and the script is aborted.

Comment: So there are catchers around all the places where gdb dispatches into Python to catch these throws and do something reasonable with them?  If you like exception style programming, I can see how that would be handy.  Feel free to file an enhancement request for this at http://bugs.llvm.org.  I note that the llvm project as a whole eschews exception style programming for all its C++ code, so you might or might not find someone already working on lldb who wants this enough to implement it...  But you never know.  If you get desperate you could try hacking it in yourself...

Comment: So, it looks like the best approximation is to call:

result.SetError("...")

and return (with error checking all the way up the stack if required).  This assumes the caller is an lldb command interface: def __call__(self, debugger, command, exe_ctx, result):...

Comment: Either that or make up your own exception class, and wrap the contents of your `__call__` in a try/catch.  If you catch something, put the exception message into the result and return.  You could make this easier to do by making up a Python decorator that does the try/catch & modifies the result and just slap that on the `__call__` methods of your command classes, or breakpoint callbacks, etc.  You'd probably want different responses for say breakpoint callbacks, where you probably want to make sure you don't auto-continue if you get an exception...